# Send currentUser id along with uploaded asset

Tags: assets-field, entry-form

I've created an entry form with an assets field. All works great, uploading to portfolio/{currentUser.id} directories. On edit forms I only want to list assets uploaded by the `currentUser` so the `.uploader(currentUser)` param on the asset query is perfect. BUT... when user uploads assets their `id` is not being recorded. I can see it listed as NULL in the assets database table. Consequently, the newly uploaded asset won't appear in the existing assets list for the `currentUser`. Make sense?

So yeah, basically I want front end form asset uploads to record the uploader's `id`.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Here's the field in my form...

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" class="block" id="account">
{{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
{{ csrfInput() }}
{{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}

{%- set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('userPortfolio') %}
{%- if field|length %}
    {# include a hidden input first so Craft knows to update the existing value, if no checkboxes are checked #}
    {{ hiddenInput('fields[userPortfolio]', '') }}
    
    {# get existing assets for this user #}
    {% set possibleAssets = craft.assets()
        .volume('cdn')
        .uploader(currentUser)
        .kind('image')
        .orderBy('filename ASC')
        .withTransforms([
            { width: 100, height: 100 }
        ])
    .all() %}

    {# get the currently related asset IDs #}
    {% set relatedAssetIds = currentUser
        ? currentUser.userPortfolio.ids()
        : [] %}

    <div class="field mb-6">
        <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="label">{{ field.name }}{%- if field.instructions %} <span class="label-hint">{{ field.instructions }}</span>{%- endif %}</label>
        {%- if possibleAssets|length %}
            <p class="control">
                <table class="table is-fullwidth">
                    <thead>
                        <th class="is-narrow"><span class="is-hidden">Checkboxes</span></th>
                        <th class="is-narrow">Photo</th>
                        <th>Filename</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="has-text-grey-light">Uncheck an image and save the form to hide it on your public portfolio</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        {%- for possibleAsset in possibleAssets %}
                            <tr>
                                <td class="is-narrow is-vcentered">
                                    {{ input('checkbox', 'fields[userPortfolio][]', possibleAsset.id, {
                                        checked: possibleAsset.id in relatedAssetIds
                                    }) }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="is-narrow is-vcentered">
                                    {{ possibleAsset.getImg({width: 48, height: 48}) }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="is-vcentered">
                                    {{ possibleAsset.filename }} {{ possibleAsset.folderId }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {%- endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </p>
        {%- endif %}

        {%- if currentUser.userPortfolio|length < 10 %}
            <p class="control">
                <div class="file is-fullwidth">
                    <label class="file-label">
                        <input type="file" name="fields[userPortfolio][]" class="file-input">
                        <span class="file-cta">
                            <span class="file-icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="file-label">Upload a photo</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </p>

        {%- else %}
            <p>You have reached your maximum 10 allowed photos.</p>

        {%- endif %}
    </div>
{%- endif %}

<div class="field is-grouped">
    <p class="control">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button is-link">Save Changes</button>
    </p>
    <p class="control">
        <a href="{{ url('account') }}" class="button is-light">Cancel</a>
    </p>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It would help to post your code?

Comment: Sure. I've added my code to the question.

Comment: I tried your code and can confirm what you're seeing. Just filed a [bug report](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6456) on your behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the assist. Just updated my Craft and all sorted.

Comment: Fixed in Craft CMS 3.4.30 - as of 7/27/20.